# Is [filter] about [filtering]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Are [filter](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filter) and [filtering](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/filtering) the same thing? The former has the following tag except while the latter has none:

> Usually related with text filtering of some kind, like logs. This may also refer to email filtering. Note that there are other tags that are more appropriate for network and spam filtering.

Shall we make them synonymous?

Answer (score 2):

I waited long to answer you as I'm uncertain for that one. I'm in between, as it could mean two distinct thing, but I see your case where each are used interchangeably.

From my understanding filter mean more like a proxy, spamassasin, or help on a system that filter request (ex; how can I filter email on exchange ?), while filtering are more indept, like filtering clause inside a firewall in example.

I would follow what the community decide, as such I suggest we could maybe make a poll with two answers, a simple *yes* create it synonymous and a *no*.